# I need one coroutine wait until next friday for the execution of sub coroutine

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am completely new to python and asyncio, so I need some help

Basically, I need  to make the coroutine to sleep until Friday 9:00 pm, doing this every week

> schedule_friday_night

```
async def schedule_friday_night(arg):
    #  schedule mechanism for coroutine to be called every Friday    
      await send_friday_night(arg)
```

> send_friday_night

```
async def send_friday_night(arg):
      await print(arg)
```

Comment: you will need to use `cron` or a scheduling library like `apscheduler`, aside from that this question is not suitable for this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many schedulers libraries like [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule), [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html), [appscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/) or even some AMPQ like [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/).

My recommendation is appscheduler, it's quite powerfull and easy to setup:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler() # you can use AsyncIOScheduler too inside asyncio loop

@sched.scheduled_job("cron", day_of_week="fri")
def friday_job():
    print("it's friday!")


sched.start()
```