# how to create scheduler in fastapi (uvicorn server)

Tags: python, fastapi, scheduler, uvicorn

I am working on a python service in which i have to create one FastAPI rest endpoint
and along with that 2 scheduler tasks should be run in background.

how can we implement scheduler in FastAPI ?
if it's not feasible what would be the best way to implement such requirement , creating two services would be the right way ?

Thanks & regards,
Aru

Comment: Have you looked at any existing libraries? https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/ (APScheduler has async support as well) or https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ are two options.

Comment: can these be integrated with fastapi ? along with restapi , there are 2 othere processes that need to be scheduled

Comment: I'm not sure why apscheduler wouldn't work; it's the most complete scheduler library for Python at least. If you want anything else, you probably want to use a cron setup (inside a VM, docker or k8s) or a multi process setup in a container. Try it.

Comment: Thank you let me try the suggested options

Comment: You can check that topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70488435/i-need-one-coroutine-wait-until-next-friday-for-the-execution-of-sub-coroutine/70488709#70488709
Just use AsyncIOScheduler

Answer (score 5):

I has passed troubleled times until a i found a solution what it's works for me.
You can use the [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/index.html).

Let me show you a quick example of how it works.

In your `main.py`, or other module you use to start you application:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
# Bellow the import create a job that will be executed on background
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


test_list = ["1"] * 10
    
# Here you create the function do you want to schedule
     
def check_list_len():
    global test_list
    logger.info(f"check_list_len：{len(test_list)}")

@app.on_event('startup')
def init_data():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(check_list_len, 'cron', second='*/5')
    scheduler.start()
```

So, the decorator `@app.on_event('startup')` will run the function `init_data` which contains the schedule.
In this exemple, the schedule will run `check_list_len` function every 5 seconds.

To see more usages exemples you can search in  the documentation.

In [this](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/tree/3.x/examples/?at=master) GitHub page, have some examples of usage.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: on_event is deprecated, right? o you know how to refactor it to use lifespan instead?

Answer (score 3):

Extending the answer from Gabriel
This is how to do it using lifespan, because on_event('startup') was deprecated.

```
import datetime
from fastapi import FastAPI
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

def printit():
    print(datetime.datetime.now())


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app:FastAPI):
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(printit,"interval",minutes = 1)
    scheduler.start()
    yield

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

@app.get("/")
async def test():
    return "Ok"
```